# A right triangle: integer legs and a hypotenuse of $1000\sqrt3$

Tags: geometry, number-theory, triangles

How do I prove there is no right triangle with integer legs and a hypotenuse of $1000\sqrt3$?

Comment: $ \iff \ x^2+y^2=3,000,000$ has no integer solution...

Comment: Use Pythagoras' Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $1000\sqrt3$ was the hypotenuse of a right triangle with integer legs, we could write its square, 3 million, as the sum of two squares. However, this factors as $2^6\cdot3\cdot5^6$, the prime 3 of form $4n+3$ appearing an odd number (1) of times. [Therefore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) 3 million is not a sum of two squares and the given hypotenuse cannot be that of an integer-legged right triangle.

Comment: Is it enough just to say that the prime 3 appears an odd number of times? What is the value of the form of 4n+3?

Comment: @Wasp Yes, saying that 3 appears an odd number of times, _and that it is of the form $4n+3$ (meaning that it leaves a remainder of 3 when divided by 4)_, would be enough. Look at the theorem statement in the link.